# Make a clustering using python with data from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, visualization

there is a error i am facing. i want to do clustering with the data i've extracted from the database using python. i have used pyodbc python package for connection between sql server and visual studio. i've created a db and then print the data(which is shown in the picture) but each data is in list data type, i've tried converting the list to strings it shows more error.

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodbc as pyodbc
import seaborn as sns
from tabulate import tabulate
conx_string = "driver={SQL Server}; server=IE3BLT7ZFGXD3\SQLEXPRESS; database=DB01; trusted_connection=YES;"
with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT firstname from Custlog")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    

with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT gender from Custlog")
    data1 = cursor.fetchall()
    
    

with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT age from Custlog")
    data2 = cursor.fetchall()
    

with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT dept from Custlog")
    data3 = cursor.fetchall()
    

with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT id from Custlog")
    data4 = cursor.fetchall()
    
  

with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    conx.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    conx.setencoding('latin1')
    cursor.execute("SELECT team_no from Custlog")
    data5 = cursor.fetchall()
    
   

table = {'Firstname':data, 'Gender':data1, 'Age':data2,'Department':data3,'Id':data4,'Team_no':data5}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
print(df)
sns.lineplot( df['Age'], df['Team_no'])
```

[o/p for printing the data extracted from db using python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68CHp.png)

```
C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py:36: FutureWarning: Pass the following variables as keyword args: x, y. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py", line 1479, in categorical_order
    order = vector.cat.categories
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 182, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 2717, in __init__
    self._validate(data)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 2726, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype")
AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\......\source\repos\demo1\demo1\demo1.py", line 62, in <module>
    sns.lineplot( df['Age'], df['Team_no'])
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 708, in lineplot
    p._attach(ax)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py", line 1137, in _attach
    seed_data = categorical_order(seed_data)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py", line 1483, in categorical_order
    order = vector.unique()
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2088, in unique
    return super().unique()
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 989, in unique
    result = unique1d(values)
  File "C:\Users\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 440, in unique
    uniques = table.unique(values)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5361, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5310, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The `fetchall()` function returns an array of `pyodbc.Row` objects (or tuples, depending on version). Instead of `data = cursor.fetchall()` have you tried assignments converting to 1-dimensional arrays of values with something like `data = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]`?

Comment: hi , Thank you, the data type is changed. now i can able to plot a bar graph. can u help me with doing clustering analysis with this data?